# how to make date comparison more efficient in javascript/typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, datetime, ngx-charts

I have a asynchronous data I am loading from Firebase Firestore with this function

```
  graphDataSubscription;
  //dataCounter;    
  passTotalCalData;
  totalCalories;
  dates=[];
  caloriesData=[];
  getGraphDateCalories() {    
    if(this.graphDataSubscription){
      this.graphDataSubscription.unsubscribe()
    }
    this.graphDataSubscription = this.mealService.grabMealGraphDataCalories(this.startDate, this.gatheredUid.uid).subscribe(items => {
      this.dates = []
      this.passTotalCalData = []
      //this.dataCounter = 0;
      this.totalCalories=0;
      this.caloriesData=[];
      items.forEach( item => {
        //this.dataCounter++        
        var data: any =  item.data()
        this.passTotalCalData.push(data.calories)
        this.caloriesData.push(data);
        this.totalCalories += data.calories;
        this.dates.push(moment(data.date).locale(window.navigator.language).format("DD MMM"))
      })
      console.log("data acquired");
      this.calendarData = this.getCalendarData();
      this.calendarData = [...this.calendarData];      
    })
  }
```

then I am trying to insert gathered values to an object to show in a chart which requires a specific object format. It is a HeatMap chart so it must include whole previous year days even there is not a data for each day. [like in this link](https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-charts/#/ngx-charts/calendar)

this is the function I am doing the date comparison, It takes almost 12 seconds even if the asynchronous data is gathered within a second.

```
  calendarData: any[] = [];
  getCalendarData(): any[] {
    //console.log("begin")
    // today
    const now = new Date();
    const todaysDay = now.getDate();
    const thisDay = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), todaysDay);

    // Monday
    const thisMonday = new Date(thisDay.getFullYear(), thisDay.getMonth(), todaysDay - thisDay.getDay() + 1);
    const thisMondayDay = thisMonday.getDate();
    const thisMondayYear = thisMonday.getFullYear();
    const thisMondayMonth = thisMonday.getMonth();

    // 52 weeks before monday
    const calendarData = [];
    const getDate = d => new Date(thisMondayYear, thisMondayMonth, d);
    for (let week = -52; week <= 0; week++) {
      const mondayDay = thisMondayDay + week * 7;
      const monday = getDate(mondayDay);

      // one week
      const series = [];
      for (let dayOfWeek = 7; dayOfWeek > 0; dayOfWeek--) {
        const date = getDate(mondayDay - 1 + dayOfWeek);

        // skip future dates
        if (date > now) {
          continue;
        }

        // value
        var value = 0;
        console.log("assigning to the object begins")
        this.caloriesData.forEach(data => {

          if (data["date"] === date.toLocaleDateString('en-CA')) {
            value = data["calories"];
            //console.log("condition granted");
            return;

          }
        });
        console.log("assigning to the object ends")


        series.push({
          date,
          name: weekdayName.format(date),
          value
        });
      }

      calendarData.push({
        name: monday.toString(),
        series
      });
    }

    return calendarData;
  }
```

I know this is too much code but I wasn't sure how to create a minimal example with this specific problem.
So is there a way to make this comparison faster?

this part is taking so long I mean it's a for each with in two nested for loops but I still don't understand why comparing these dates takes so much time

```
var value = 0;
console.log("assigning to the object begins")
this.caloriesData.forEach(data => {

  if (data["date"] === date.toLocaleDateString('en-CA')) {
    value = data["calories"];
    //console.log("condition granted");
    return;

  }
});
console.log("assigning to the object ends")
```

Comment: `comparison` is a pretty vague term. What do you mean exactly?

Comment: Would it be possible to explain the comparison so we don't have to go through all that? Are you looking for dates before today, after, in a range of dates? Thanks.

Comment: I added an edit, to explain the "comparison", really  hope it's more clear @CristianTraìna

Comment: You use moments in the top script - is there a reason you are not using moment for all of your date math and comparison (what moments calls query)?

Comment: @RandyCasburn there is no reason not to use it, I just did't think it would make such big difference, I will try now, Thank you

Comment: it will reduce your code and and it is optimized to do the sorts of things you are doing.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I did't think It would help this much, completely solved the problem, really appreciate it

Comment: Glad you got it sorted and happy to help.